# Symfony 3.3: unable to add and remove items of the same entity with collection form type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I am new to Symfony, so I started with the official tutorial, installed Symfony framework 3.3.2 and worked through the tutorial while customizing entities, controllers, forms and views to my specific needs.

So basically I have an entity named BasePreset, there are already a couple of rows in the DB, and I finally have managed to create a form collection type that renders a list of editable BasePreset entity fields with 'add' and 'remove' links: the 1st adds new blank fields to the list, and every 'remove' link removes the corresponding fields from DOM. Everything according to docs.

So I succeed to update the existing fields (I see the right changes in form HTML after reloading and in the DB as well).

The problem is, add/delete not working. No errors given. Checked in Chrome Dev tools: parameters sent as expected.

I used the following documentation (and a lot of googling of course) regarding the form builder:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Now, in [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) is stated:

> You have to create both addTag() and removeTag() methods, otherwise
>   the form will still use setTag() even if by_reference is false. You'll
>   learn more about the removeTag() method later in this article.

At this moment I don't have any referenced subentity as it is described in the examples. I just want be able to edit the same plain entity, including adding new items and deleting existing. Maybe I'm wrong, but this seems as kind of a trivial basic goal in my mind. I don't understand how to properly add 'setBasePreset' and 'removeBasePreset' methods to the 'BasePreset' entity itself.

Of course I can skip using the form builder, but I'd like to leverage its power as a part of the framework. Any advice, example, maybe pointing to some relevant doc/tutorial that I missed - will be greatly appreciated.

**Post example (with one  addition and one removal):**

```
base_presets[base_presets][5][name]:new_preset
base_presets[base_presets][5][description]:new, not really added
base_presets[base_presets][0][name]:ffffas44432df
base_presets[base_presets][0][description]:asdfffff2333
base_presets[base_presets][2][name]:ffffasdf2222
base_presets[base_presets][2][description]:asdff3fff2333
base_presets[base_presets][3][name]:yoyoshka
base_presets[base_presets][3][description]:nananaf
base_presets[base_presets][4][name]:123fffdsaasdf
base_presets[base_presets][4][description]:pop123
base_presets[_token]:H2QwRHdvZW1WAdc6VTONnspxvH1U-oC8rCEEprDdMCQ
```

**The 'BasePresetsType' class:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class BasePresetsType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('base_presets', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => BasePresetType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false // also tried 'true' but without any success
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

**The 'BasePresetType' class:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\BasePreset;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class BasePresetType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => BasePreset::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**The controller method:**

```
<?php
// ...
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/list_base_presets", name="list_base_presets")
     */
    public function listBasePresetsAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $base_presets = $em->getRepository("AppBundle\Entity\BasePreset")->findAll();

        $form = $this->createForm(BasePresetsType::class, array('base_presets' => $base_presets));

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $current_route = $request->get('_route');

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($base_presets as $base_preset) {
                $em->persist($base_preset);
            }
            $em->flush();
            // ... do other work - like sending an email, etc..
            // maybe set a 'flash' success message for the user
            return $this->redirectToRoute($current_route);
        }
        return $this->render('manage_params/list_base_presets.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

**The view:**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form.base_presets) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.base_presets) }}
    <ul class="base-presets" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.base_presets.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
        {% for base_preset in form.base_presets %}
            <li class="base-preset-item">
                {{ form_errors(base_preset) }}
                {{ form_widget(base_preset) }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li class="form-submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        var $collection_holder;
        // Setup an "add a base preset" link
        var $add_base_preset_link = $('<a href="#" class="add_base_preset_link">Add a base preset</a>');
        var $new_link_li = $('<li></li>').append($add_base_preset_link);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Get the ul that holds the collection of base presets
            $collection_holder = $('ul.base-presets');
            // add the "add a base preset" anchor and li to the tags ul
            $collection_holder.prepend($new_link_li);
            // count the current form inputs we have, use that as the new index when inserting a new item
            $collection_holder.data('index', $collection_holder.find('li.base-preset-item').length);

            $add_base_preset_link.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addBasePresetForm($collection_holder, $new_link_li);
            });

            // add a delete link to all of the existing base presets form li elements
            $collection_holder.find('li.base-preset-item').each(function () {
                addBasePresetFormDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        });

        function addBasePresetForm($collection_holder, $new_link_li) {
            // Get the data-prototype
            var prototype = $collection_holder.data('prototype');
            // Get the new index
            var index = $collection_holder.data('index');
            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to instead be a number based on how many items we have
            var new_form = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);
            // increment the index for the next item
            $collection_holder.data('index', index + 1);
            // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a base preset" link li
            var $new_form_li = $('<li class="base-preset-item"></li>').append(new_form);
            $new_link_li.after($new_form_li);
            addBasePresetFormDeleteLink($new_form_li);
        }

        function addBasePresetFormDeleteLink($base_preset_form_li) {
            var $remove_form_a = $('<a href="#">Delete this base preset</a>');
            $base_preset_form_li.append($remove_form_a);
            $remove_form_a.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $base_preset_form_li.remove();
            })
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**And, finally, the longest listing - the 'BasePreset' entity class:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * Class BasePreset
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="base_presets")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message="There should be only one (unique) base preset")
 */
class BasePreset {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BaseParamsGroup", mappedBy="base_preset")
     */
    private $base_params_groups;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4000)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
     */
    private $updated;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->base_params_groups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return BasePreset
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return BasePreset
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     *
     * @return BasePreset
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @return BasePreset
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Add baseParamsGroup
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BaseParamsGroup $baseParamsGroup
     *
     * @return BasePreset
     */
    public function addBaseParamsGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\BaseParamsGroup $baseParamsGroup)
    {
        $this->base_params_groups[] = $baseParamsGroup;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove baseParamsGroup
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BaseParamsGroup $baseParamsGroup
     */
    public function removeBaseParamsGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\BaseParamsGroup $baseParamsGroup)
    {
        $this->base_params_groups->removeElement($baseParamsGroup);
    }

    /**
     * Get baseParamsGroups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBaseParamsGroups()
    {
        return $this->base_params_groups;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use form without Data class, you need to access submitted data directly from form object:

```
foreach ($form->get('base_presets')->getData() as $base_preset) {
    $em->persist($base_preset);
}
```

**Update**:
That work with managing existing and persisting new ones. If you need to remove entities, you can compare entities loaded from DB with submitted ones, and then remove filtered.

Comment: It works for adding a new row, but doesn't work for deleting an existing row (still no errors, just no change). Is it resolvable? Maybe I should create some collection class to put it as Data class into the collection form type?

Comment: @a1111exe You can compare IDs from `$base_presets` with submitted ones and then call `$em->remove($notSubmittedEntity);` on each different one.

Comment: I obviously can, and probably shall do this. I'm curious if this is the only way. E.g., for subentity as in the official example there is no need to do this. This solution looks for me like a subtle hack to mitigate some lack of flexibility in the form system. Anyways, I have to move on, so it'll work for me. Could you please add this to your answer so I'll mark it accepted?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks to all you guys... But I am running through the same issue with a little difference. I have a mapping between: `Operation`, `OperationEntry` and `Product` with collections on forms to register operations (buying and sales). To save works just fine, and update is good when I just delete entries or just add entries. But if I delete and then add a new entry, the `OperationEntry::product` is NULL and redirection to `sale_show` says **'cannot find designation of NULL'** (i.e `Product::designation` through the path `entity.operationEntry[INDEX].product.designation`)